# How to delete a line from a file using python

Tags: python

I am using following code to find all the lines which contains ':' special character. Later I am trying to remove those lines from the file -

```
myFile = open('myPOST.txt', 'rb')
    myText = myFile.readlines()
    for line in myText:
             line.find(":") == "-1"
         if line.find(":"):
```

Is there any function in python that returns exactly the line where this character is found (find() returns either -1 or location of the searched character in the line) Or if I use find() only then how to delete exactly those lines for which the value of find() is -1?

Comment: If you want your line number use `for line_no, line in enumerate(myText)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [`fileinput`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/fileinput.html#fileinput.FileInput)

> Optional in-place filtering: if the keyword argument `inplace=1` is passed to `fileinput.input()` or to the `FileInput` constructor, the file is moved to a backup file and standard output is directed to the input file (if a file of the same name as the backup file already exists, it will be replaced silently). This makes it possible to write a filter that rewrites its input file in place.

`myPOST.txt`

```
abc
de:f
ghi
```

---

```
import fileinput
for line in fileinput.input('myPOST.txt', inplace=True): 
    if ':' in line:
        continue # skip it
    print line.rstrip('\n') # stdout redirected to file
```

---

`myPOST.txt`

```
abc
ghi
```

The good thing about this solution is that it doesn't use `.readlines()` which loads the whole file into memory, instead it writes to a temporary file which is renamed to the original.

Comment: `print line.rstrip()` is most likely right (who needs trailing space)  - `print line,`  is a possibility

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to do it within your existing program without having it be a command line utility like `fileinput` excels.

```
with open("myPOST.txt", "rb") as my_file:
    for line in my_file:
        if ":" not in line:
            # do whatever you want here
            # these are only the lines that do not have a ':' character
```

if you just want to find the line numbers

```
with open("myPOST.txt", "rb") as my_file:
    line_numbers = [lnum for lnum, line in enumerate(my_file) if ":" in line]
```